# Hitting a segfault when copying local vector to the value of a certain key in map

Tags: c++, vector, stl, segmentation-fault

```
class TrackSymbol
{
        protected: static std::map<int, std::vector<char> > _trackTypeToIdentificationCodeMap ;

        protected: static char _identificationCodeChars[][2] ;
} ;
```

In the implementation file:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<char> > TrackSymbol::_trackTypeToIdentificationCodeMap ;

char TrackSymbol::_identificationCodeChars[][2] =
{
    { ' ', ' ' },
    { 'S', '6' },
    { 'Z', 'U' }
} ;
```

In the constructor, I'm attempting to fill a local vector with appropriate values from _identificationCodeChars, but hitting a segfault in the copy:

```
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < sizeof( _identificationCodeChars ) / sizeof( _identificationCodeChars[0] ) ; i++ )
    {
        std::vector<char> vec ;
        vec.push_back( _identificationCodeChars[i][0] ) ;
        vec.push_back( _identificationCodeChars[i][1] ) ;

        _trackTypeToIdentificationCodeMap[i] = vec ; //Segfault here
    }
```

It's my understanding that the assignment operator will do a hard copy of the local vector, so I'm a bit confused on why it's hitting the segmentation fault. Also, with my current environment, I'm restricted to C98, so I'm unable to use things like extended initializer lists, etc.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static member variable is basically a fancy global variable. In particular the constructor of that map is called only once in that program's execution, not once for every TrackSymbol object. (However, it *is* guaranteed to run before executing the first line in `int main()`.)

It's hard to tell from just what you've said, but my guess is that you've instantiated a TrackSymbol object before `_trackTypeToIdentificationCodeMap`'s constructor has run, such as in a global variable defined before `_trackTypeToIdentificationCodeMap` or in another file. The immediate fix is to move that definition. A better fix might be to make that member variable non-static (if you can afford the performance hit) or use a singleton function (in old C++ versions, this is not guaranteed to be thread safe):

```
std::map<int, std::vector<char> > getCodeMap_internal()
{
    static char _identificationCodeChars[][2] =
    {
        { ' ', ' ' },
        { 'S', '6' },
        { 'Z', 'U' }
    } ;
    std::map<int, std::vector<char> > _trackTypeToIdentificationCodeMap;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < sizeof( _identificationCodeChars ) / sizeof( _identificationCodeChars[0] ) ; i++ )
    {
        std::vector<char> vec ;
        vec.push_back( _identificationCodeChars[i][0] ) ;
        vec.push_back( _identificationCodeChars[i][1] ) ;

        _trackTypeToIdentificationCodeMap[i] = vec ;
    }
    return _trackTypeToIdentificationCodeMap;
}

const std::map<int, std::vector<char> >& getCodeMap()
{
    static std::map<int, std::vector<char> > _trackTypeToIdentificationCodeMap
        = getCodeMap_internal();
    return _trackTypeToIdentificationCodeMap;
}
```